# Continuous function and equivalent condition

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $X$ be topological space. $T=T_\text{dis}$ means the discrete topology on $X$, $T=T_\text{ind}$ is an indiscrete  topology on $X.$

**Theorem**. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces such that every function $f\colon X\to Y$ is  continuous . Then $T_X=T_\text{dis}$  or $T_Y=T_\text{ind}.$

**Proof**. Assume $T_X\neq T_\text{dis}$, it is enough to show that $T_Y=T_\text{ind}.$ For contradiction, suppose $T_Y\neq T_\text{ind}.$ This means that there exists  $\emptyset\neq  A\subsetneq Y$ such that $A\in T_Y.$

Now, since $T_X\neq T_\text{dis}$ so there exists an $x^*\in X$ such that $\{x^*\}\not\in T_X.$ So, define a function $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $f(x^*)\in A$ and $f[X\setminus\{x^*\}]=y$ where $y\in Y\setminus A,$ such $y$ exist since $A\subsetneq Y$. But we have $f$ is not continuous since $f^{-1}(A)=\{x^*\}\not\in T_X$, as $A\in T_Y, $ which is a contradiction with assumption that says each function from $X$ to $Y$ is a continuous function.  Then, $T_Y=T_\text{ind}.$ This finishes the proof.

I think it is correct unless I misread the question.  Is that right?

Comment: Seems correct to me. The only thing I would recommend doing is maybe explicitly  stating that because $A \subsetneq Y$ then such a $y$ as given in the proof must exist, though this may be being a pedant at that point!

Comment: @user2628206, I did. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically and topologically correct (I'd say). Well done. (This just to get it off the unanswered list..).

Comment: Henno Brandsma, Thank you .